# Why doesn't __rmod__ work properly for strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting, subclassing

```
>>> class MyInt(int):
...     def __rmod__(self, other):
...         return 42
...     
>>> class MyStr(str):
...     def __rmod__(self, other):
...         return 'wat'
...     
>>> 0 % MyInt()
42
>>> '%r' % MyStr()
"''"
```

Why is the `int` subclass able to control this BinOp from the reflected side, but `str` can not?  This seems to contradict the documented [datamodel](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html).

I was hoping to use the feature to create a non-intrusive and backwards-compatible extension providing curly-braces-style handlers/formatters for the `logging` framework, but this stopped me in my tracks.  Is that a bug?

**Python 3.6.0 on Linux**. Using `collections.UserString` as a base class also has the issue. Using `bytes` as a base does not.

Comment: [This](https://bugs.python.org/issue28598) seems relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [Python issue 28598](https://bugs.python.org/issue28598). The [fast path](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.0/Python/ceval.c#L1412-L1414) for `%` string formatting in the bytecode evaluation loop wasn't checking for string subclasses. It's [fixed now](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.3/Python/ceval.c#L1459-L1462), so update your Python to v3.6.1+.

Comment: I backported the fix to 2.7 and 3.5 as well; it's part of 2.7.14 and 3.5.4.